# custom extended TableLayout not adding xml TableRows

Tags: android, class, tablelayout

I give.

I'm trying to extend the TableLayout class ( simply so I can override the onMeasure ) and I'm inflating a TableLayout that's defined in XML.

The TableLayout shows up (I can see it, due to its custom background) but the TableRows don't.

Even in the XML "Graphical Layout" of eclipse, if I force the TableLayout to be my custom extended class (com.example.MainApplication.TableLayout_Schedrunning) the nested TableRows aren't there.

However, if I change the XML to just be TableLayout, the TableRows magically appear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- this doesn't work-->
<com.example.MainApplication.Tablelayout_Schedrunning xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frmlay_schedule"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:padding="2dp"
android:background="@drawable/schedrunning_background" >
<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tblrow_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtSchedRunningHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Schedule Running"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13dp"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtCurrScheduleRunning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="11dp"/>
</TableRow>

</com.example.MainApplication.Tablelayout_Schedrunning>
```

So again, to reiterate -- if I change the above custom class to the simple `<TableLayout>`, the nested TextViews in the TableRow show up.  If I don't, they don't.
What simple thing am I missing??

Oh, and the TableLayout is a pretty standard extension:

```
public class Tablelayout_Schedrunning extends TableLayout {

public Tablelayout_Schedrunning(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Log.w("tablelayout","simple context");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Tablelayout_Schedrunning(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Log.w("tablelayout","advanced, context and attrs");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    Log.w("tablelayout","parentWidth is " + parentWidth);
    Log.w("tablelayout","parentHeight is " + parentHeight);
    //super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, (int) (parentHeight * .4));
}
```

Comment: I guess this is basic, but did you remember to call the Super class constructor?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I should add the code of my Super class to the question, It's pretty simple.  I just didn't want to bog down the question.

Comment: I'm thinking there must be something inside the extended TableLayout that deals directly with the TableRow that's inside the inflating XML that I don't know about.

Comment: why you did not add super.onMeasure

Comment: And also setLayoutParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add `super.onMeasure` and `setLayoutParams` to your extention of a `View`

Comment: you ROCK! for some reason, I'd commented out the line
`super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);`  Once I uncommented it, the TableRows show up.
No idea why, but THANK YOU!

Comment: You should always call the Super method when you extend a Class. You are extending the class (adding to it) so you call the super method and add your customization. Otherwise, you are replacing the Class constructor missing out a lot of code in the Super constructor that deal with child Views.

Comment: I honestly can't even remember why I commented it out, or when.  Something wasn't working back then (to do with the custom measured layout size), but it was extending a FrameLayout at the time.
It's always something small like that, hey?